# How do I upload a local photo and display it on an html widget without using data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to design an html javascript widget for ibook that uploads a file either from the local storage or the user takes a photo. I have this code which does exactly that. But how do I save it so it can be displayed in a photo gallery. Is this even possible without having to upload online?

Select your file:

Comment: You can use dropbox javascript api to upload & use that url to display it any point of time. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/sdks/js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a free webhosting for this. I have been using [WebNG](http://www.webng.com) for free and for a period of over 5 years. Upload the files there, map the file names to show and you are good to go live.

Comment: I want to know add the photos to the widget with out uploading it online. I don't think this is possible with javascript.

Comment: You can write a rest service (WCF for instance) for saving the files to server, and sending files to the service through ajax.

Comment: Imagine there is no internet. I want to write an offline widget that takes a photo as an input and then save it to the ipad for future reference.

Comment: That might be impossible now, if we are talking about web.